# SAM CLI - Why does it take weeks for new versions of well-known libraries to be available?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli

It happened to us many times, we try to use a newly issued version of a certain well-known library in Python (the new version is available on Conda and PIP), but we try to use it via AWS SAM CLI, the build fails saying something like this:

```
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {xxxx==x.y.z(wheel)}
```

We go back to a previous version, it all works fine.

Is there some sort of AWS-specific package repo that is late to update libraries? and how can we ensure our app uses the latest and greatest libraries (especially if a certain library has a major bug or security issue)?

Last example is pymongo:

```
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {pymongo==3.12.0(wheel)}
```

But this is not the only one, we had it with a handful of major libraries, the above version of pymongo was published to pip more than two weeks ago!

My development workstation is Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above happened in SAM CLI version: 1.23.0, we updated to version 1.27.2, and all works fine!

Didn't expect SAM version to impact that, but here you go!